# Wifi USB dongle not working on 16.04

Tags: wireless

I have a wireless dongle that seems to be installed correctly, but no wireless adapter appears in my network manager and I can't debug the issue.

I've ran wireless-info from: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and my wireless-info.txt is: https://pastebin.com/nddpF5S9

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu` and then: `sudo iwlist scan` Are there now scan results? We don't need to see the actual result, just tell us if you see any. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Disregard me for the moment.  If I say white and @chili555 says, black: believe him, not me!  **:-) :-) :-)**

Comment: @Fabby His device is claimed by two drivers, rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu, both of which loaded and conflict. I think we need a blacklist!

Comment: ah ok so i did sudo `modeprobe -r rtl8192cu` and ....now i don't see the device using `ifconfig -a`

Comment: @chili555 If it would help, sinjax is already in the AU General chat...

Comment: @chili555 i tried disabling rtl8xxxu and enabling rtl8192cu and the device appears again. iwlist scan says wlxec3dfde1109a Interface doesn't support scanning: Network is down. I tried `ifup`, no dice.

Answer (score 2):

We have seen many rtl8192cu cases where two drivers load and conflict. Let's blacklist one and see if it helps; if not, we'll try the other.

From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

If not, we'll reverse it:

```
sudo -i
rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

Depending on your results, we'll further refine this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In then end I upgraded to 18.04 on this machine and the dongle worked. Not the most satisfying result but hopefully it saves someone time.